# Adding animations to expandable folders

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a 4 expandable containers in a single row.
After clicking the title the container expands and the other containers collapse/shrink.

I'm struggling with adding some animation/transition to the action of expanding/collapsing/shrinking to all of them.

Nothing I tried works.

Anyone knows how to add some animations to expand/collapse these containers to look smoothly?

```
This is the code: https://codepen.io/Micha-Molka/pen/BaGrzpw

<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <h3 class="title">Title 1</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="color color1"></div>
      <div class="opis">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sed ex turpis. Vivamus malesuada ante sit amet ullamcorper hendrerit.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <h3 class="title">Title 2</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="color color2"></div>
      <div class="opis">
        Sed vestibulum posuere dictum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut sodales odio mi, nec interdum felis lobortis a.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <h3 class="title">Title 3</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="color color3"></div>
      <div class="opis">
        Nullam bibendum, velit vel feugiat vestibulum, quam turpis dictum mauris, non iaculis tellus sem ac mi.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <h3 class="title">Title 4</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="color color4"></div>
      <div class="opis">
        Phasellus sodales pharetra diam at luctus. In egestas nisi eu urna ullamcorper, at tempus lacus ultrices.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: max-width 13s;
}

.header {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.container .color {
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 200px; /* Wysokość kwadratów - dostosuj według potrzeb */
}

.container .color1 {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.container .color2 {
  background-color: #00ff00;
}

.container .color3 {
  background-color: #0000ff;
}

.container .color4 {
  background-color: #ff00ff;
}

.container.expanded {
  flex-basis: 40%;
}

.container.collapsed {
  flex-basis: auto;
}

.container .opis {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  max-width: 50%;
  transition: opacity 3s;
}

.container.expanded .opis {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  animation: fadeIn 3s forwards;
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
  }
}

const containers = document.querySelectorAll(".container");

containers.forEach((container) => {
  const header = container.querySelector(".header");
  const content = container.querySelector(".content");

  header.addEventListener("click", () => {
    containers.forEach((c) => {
      if (c !== container) {
        c.classList.add("collapsed");
        c.classList.remove("expanded");
      }
    });
    container.classList.toggle("collapsed");
    container.classList.toggle("expanded");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can't transition from `auto` to `40%`, so I had to change that to `0%`. Same for `display` can't animate `none` to `block`. Also make sure you declare the right property for transition (I went with `all`). The animation `forward` should also be backwards therefore removed. I also tried to transition the `width` of the text element. `overflow-x: hidden` for the `.row`.

It's a start.

```js
const containers = document.querySelectorAll(".container");

containers.forEach((container) => {
  const header = container.querySelector(".header");
  const content = container.querySelector(".content");

  header.addEventListener("click", () => {
    containers.forEach((c) => {
      if (c !== container) {
        c.classList.add("collapsed");
        c.classList.remove("expanded");
      }
    });
    container.classList.toggle("collapsed");
    container.classList.toggle("expanded");
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 3s;
}

.header {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.container .color {
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 200px;
  /* Wysokość kwadratów - dostosuj według potrzeb */
}

.container .color1 {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.container .color2 {
  background-color: #00ff00;
}

.container .color3 {
  background-color: #0000ff;
}

.container .color4 {
  background-color: #ff00ff;
}

.container.expanded {
  flex-basis: 40%;
}

.container.collapsed {
  flex-basis: 0%;
}

.container .opis {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  /* padding: 10px; */
  line-height: 1.5;
  max-width: 50%;
  width: 0%;
  transition: all 3s;
}

.container.expanded .opis {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 50%;
  animation: fadeIn 3s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <h3 class="title">Title 1</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="color color1"></div>
      <div class="opis">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sed ex turpis. Vivamus malesuada ante sit amet ullamcorper hendrerit.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <h3 class="title">Title 2</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="color color2"></div>
      <div class="opis">
        Sed vestibulum posuere dictum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut sodales odio mi, nec interdum felis lobortis a.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <h3 class="title">Title 3</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="color color3"></div>
      <div class="opis">
        Nullam bibendum, velit vel feugiat vestibulum, quam turpis dictum mauris, non iaculis tellus sem ac mi.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <h3 class="title">Title 4</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="color color4"></div>
      <div class="opis">
        Phasellus sodales pharetra diam at luctus. In egestas nisi eu urna ullamcorper, at tempus lacus ultrices.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```